# how to automatically publish something on the facebook timeline after registration on website

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

maybe the subject is not clear enough.
What I need is:
people come to visit my website
they decide to register
after registration is completed, a facebook app of mine should publish on theri timeline "Hello, I have just become member of TheWebSite.com - Would you like to register? Click here"

Is there any tutorial on how to achieve that with php?
I found many things on the internet, but most of them are outdated and some others are extremely complicated.

Any lead?
Thank you very much

Comment: You can't automatically do that, you would require the Users permission to post to their timeline.

Comment: ok, you mean that a window should popup and say "Hi, TheWebSite would like to publish something on your timeline. Consent?", don't you? That's ok with me, but how can that be done? Thank you

Comment: I don't know whether it would happen like that, but something like that yes. I would suggest you follow one of the tutorials that you've found and try to make the most of it, and then come back with any problems you've run into, SO isn't going to provide you with a step-by-step guide.